# How to add equally sized watermark to opencart images

Tags: php, opencart, watermark

I want to set an equally sized watermark for all images, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've managed to add watermark, but I guess because the product images are with different sizes, so does the watermark become with different size. I'm using the code from this URL to add the watermark - http://www.deshisoft.com/how-to-add-watermark-to-image-for-opencart/

Answer (score 0):

Opencart 2.1.0.2

In /catalog/model/tool/**image.php**
find this

```
        $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
        $image->resize($width, $height);
        $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
```

and add

```
        $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
        $image->resize($width, $height);

        // add this two lines
        $imageW = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . 'watermark.png'); // link to your watermark image
        $image->watermark($imageW, 'bottomright');  // topleft, topright, bottomleft or bottomright

        $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
```

and your watermark will be the same size on each image.

If you add this two lines before

```
$image->resize($width, $height);
```

your watermark will be resized with each image, so could be different size on each one.

And of course remove images from  **/image/cache** folder.